# I'm trying to connect my sql server to my C# winforms on visual studio 2022 but it keeps saying unable to connect to host

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, visual-studio-2022

Firstly, here is the code for the form I am trying to connect to the sql server which is on the same computer.

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Database_Project2
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1; Database=BikeCompany; Uid=Fred; Pwd=1234;");

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
}`
```

When I go to run the code this is what pops up...
Exception User-Unhandled
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

When I connect to SQL Server Management Studio it doesn't ask me for a user id or password I just click connect. So, originally when first tried connecting the database to the winforms I didn't have a username or password in the conneciton string. So I added a user to the database hence now the user id and password. Unfortunately that also didn't work and gave me the same exception. After that I tried copy and pasting the exact connection string you get when connecting your sql server to visual studio and alas it still wasn't connecting. I'm honestly so confused as to how or what I need to connect an sql database to a winforms in visual studio. Any help as to what I'm doing wrong is apprieciated...

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about what kind of server you're using. Are you trying to connect to MySQL or SQL Server? Your code is written for MySQL but SQL Server Management Studio connects to SQL Server, so you're talking about two entirely different things.

Comment: The title rather ambiguous, as well.  You say *"my sql server"*, but does that mean "MySQL server" or "my SQL Server"? Case matters, even in the names.

Comment: I'm trying to connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. What would I need in order to connect with that?

Comment: Well, no, in that case, you want to connect to SQL Server (full stop). SQL Server Management Studio is just another client that connects to SQL Server.

Comment: You want `SqlConnection` in `System.Data.SqlClient`, not `MySqlConnection`.

Comment: Now I'm getting this: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1069 The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.

Comment: You need to change the object from MySqlConnection to SqlConnection.

Comment: I figured it out. You have to first install system.data.sqlclient from the nuget manager and then it'll recognize that sqlconnection syntax. From there I copied the connection path from the server explorer in visual studio and it finally let me connect to the database. Thank you all for pointing out that I needed to use sql and not mysql.

Comment: @Fredcalascibetta to be very clear, SQL Server and MySQL are entirely different databases. SQL Server is made by microsoft, uses Transact-SQL dialect, while MySQL is owned by Oracle and uses MySQL dialect. These dialects are very different, as T-SQL supports both the SQL standard as well as its own propietary stuff, while MySQL syntax does some things that sideline the SQL standard (major example is `""` vs `''` for escaping strings, just to align with Java). They use 2 different connectors, hence the need to get diff packages from NuGet and to use separate namespaces

Comment: In sum, what you are doing here has *nothing* to do with MySQL, so be careful when conducting further research while working on this project. All resources should be SQL Server, and T-SQL, and stick closely to the Microsoft documentation. Remove the MySQL data connector package from the project entirely so there is no spillover, as those will cause you issues